# Added lights to circuit, now lights flicker

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light

I have 2 lights powered from a circuit in a hallway right below my attic access. I had 1 light in the attic, but I ran some wire and added 3 more lights and to make it daylight up in the attic.

When the lights are off in the attic, the hall lights are fine. When I turn the attic lights on, I get a pretty rapid flickering from the hall lights only. The attic lights don't flicker at all when turned on.

The attic lights I got are these 4 blade LED things [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07VRDS785/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VRDS785)

The hall lights are typical recessed canned lights. I don't think the circuit is anywhere near overloaded since the 4 added lights only add up to about 400W total, plus 2 recessed lights.

If the problem was with the newly installed lights, then wouldn't those lights be flickering instead of the hall lights that are fine otherwise?

Comment: Flickering can also be from a loose connection.  I would recheck all connections for tightness.  Most connections now require the use of a torque driver for the correct tightness.   LEDs seem to show this more.

Comment: Are any of these lights on dimmers or electronics controls?

Comment: Can you upload pictures showing all the connections from the old circuit to the new lights? You may have something messed up in the wiring, possibly ending up with serial instead of parallel wiring. Also, these new lights are pretty definitely not UL or ETL listed. Not as much of an issue if you are using them as screw-in devices - and in fact, if you are using them as screw-in devices then try temporarily swapping for ordinary bulbs (LED or incandescent or CFL) and see if that changes things.